# Most appropriate test for count data

Tags: anova, count-data, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test, ecology

So I've performed an experiment whereby I had 12 1km transects. 6 of these were along rivers running through agricultural land and 6 through woodland. These were arranged in pairs so that each agri site had a nearby "paired" woodland site on the same river catchment. My experiment was to see if otter activity differed between agri and woodland and this was done by collecting otter poop. The number of poops counted ranged from 0 (only 1 site had <6) to 20+.
I was just wondering which test would be appropriate to check if there is a difference between them.
Anova was originally suggested but does that work for count data?
Would Kruskal-Wallis or Mann-Whitney U be more appropriate?

Please help!

Comment: FWIW, this is a perfectly fine study, but an observational one; it isn't truly an experiment.

Comment: Why not a model explicitly designed for count data? If you don't have covariates, it sounds like you might consider a simple 6x2 contingency table for which a test of homogeneity of proportions might be suitable.

Comment: Thanks! Erm, I guess I do have a covariate in the form of "Pair" - or which river catchment the site was in.

Answer (score -1):

Ultimately before using ANOVA you would have to check the assumptions.  From your statement about the amount of zeros and skewness it is likely that variance is greater than the mean, which implies that your data may be Poisson, negative binomial or zero inflated. A simple approach would use a non-parametic test. For example one could test to see if there is a difference between the medians, which can be conducted by using the Wilcoxon Rank Sum (WSR) test. However, a more robust research design would use Generalized Estimating Equations, or the Empirical Bayes comparison group or the Before and After method. The later are cost prohibitive, because they require sufficient sample sizes of high quality data as well as a least one week worth of work from a statistician to determine if a association exists.